# How to cache and find first match in pivot table withing laravel collections?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have these tables

- User
- role
- user_roles

In user_roles table there are following fields

- start_date
- end_date
- is_active

How can I read all active and not expired roles if current user and put them in cache for one hour?

Is there any way clean cache on one role deactivation?

Comment: Why all those tags?

Comment: this is my first question, which ones should i remove?

Comment: Note that a pivot table is a connection between two tables. You right now don't make a connection because there is no "user_id" and "role_id" foreign key in the pivot table. Read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship is not defined correctly. This should be like the following:

#### User model

```
class User {
    public function roles() {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Role::class);
    }
}
```

#### Role model

```
class Role {
    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany(App\User::class);
    }
}
```

Now create the appropriate pivot table to deal with this relationship

#### role_user schema

```
Schema::create('role_user', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->timestamp('start_date');
    $table->timestamp('end_date');
    $table->integer('is_active')->default(0); //change to 1 if you want always to be active
});
```

Now modify our `User` class and add `->withPivot('start_date', 'end_date', 'is_active');` to our `roles()` relationship.

#### Updated User model

```
class User {
    public function roles() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Role::class')->withPivot('start_date', 'end_date', 'is_active');
    }
}
```

*But wait, this doesn't get me active roles for my user?!* No problem, let's do that with a query scope.

```
class User { 
    //...

    public function scopeOnlyActiveRoles ($query) {
        return $query->whereHas('roles', function($query){
            return $query->where('start_date', '>=', Carbon::now())
                         ->where('end_date', '<=', Carbon::now())
                         ->where('is_active', 1);
        });
    }
}
```